# scrheadings disable slanted text in header

Tags: fonts, header-footer, scrpage2

I'm usually using `scrheadings` pagestyle from the `scrpage2` package to customize my header / footer. But it uses slanted shape as default. How can I switch that behaviour to use the normal font shape? A MWE might be:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,pointednumbers]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopf- und Fußzeilen

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\cohead{Das ist ein Test.}

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `scrpage2` outdated?

Comment: Off topic: replace the obsolete option `pointednumbers` by `numbers=endperiod`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was on my ToDo list: Find an alternative for pointednumbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Here is how to change the headers font:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\upshape}
\cohead{Das ist ein Test.}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]